# dual boot windows XP/debian, I can't boot windows

Tags: debian, boot, dual-boot, grub2

I tried to set up a dual boot windows xp/debian. I installed Debian after windows, and now I can't boot windows xp.
I have grub2.

I tried to directly modify /boot/grub/grub.cfg with

```
menuentry 'WinXP'  {
    insmod part_msdos
    set root='(hd0,msdos4)'
    insmod chain
    chainloader +1
}
```

but I can't make that work. When I select winXP in the grub menu, I get a black screen and the system restarts.

Please, any hint?

---

Output of `df -h`

```
Filesystem                                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                                                   30G  8.3G   20G  30% /
udev                                                     10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                   177M  628K  177M   1% /run
/dev/disk/by-uuid/4eba1bb8-14f7-4920-a9c3-2fb8894626d3   30G  8.3G   20G  30% /
tmpfs                                                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                   764M  232K  764M   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda6                                                92G  2.3G   85G   3% /data
/dev/sda5                                               9.9G  258M  9.1G   3% /home
```

---

output of `sudo fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00089f15

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *   204796620   267710463    31456922   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       267710464   271904767     2097152   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3       271906814   488397167   108245177    5  Extended
/dev/sda4           16128   204796619   102390246    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5       271906816   292878335    10485760   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       292880384   488397167    97758392   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

---

Output of `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  load_env
fi
set default="0"
if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function load_video {
  insmod vbe
  insmod vga
  insmod video_bochs
  insmod video_cirrus
}

insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4eba1bb8-14f7-4920-a9c3-2fb8894626d3
if loadfont /usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then
  set gfxmode=640x480
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  insmod part_msdos
  insmod ext2
  set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4eba1bb8-14f7-4920-a9c3-2fb8894626d3
  set locale_dir=($root)/boot/grub/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
set timeout=5
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4eba1bb8-14f7-4920-a9c3-2fb8894626d3
insmod png
if background_image /usr/share/images/desktop-base/joy-grub.png; then
  set color_normal=white/black
  set color_highlight=black/white
else
  set menu_color_normal=cyan/blue
  set menu_color_highlight=white/blue
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.2.0-4-686-pae' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    load_video
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4eba1bb8-14f7-4920-a9c3-2fb8894626d3
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.2.0-4-686-pae ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-686-pae root=UUID=4eba1bb8-14f7-4920-a9c3-2fb8894626d3 ro  noapic nolapic
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-686-pae
}
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.2.0-4-686-pae (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    load_video
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4eba1bb8-14f7-4920-a9c3-2fb8894626d3
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.2.0-4-686-pae ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-686-pae root=UUID=4eba1bb8-14f7-4920-a9c3-2fb8894626d3 ro single 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-686-pae
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Comment: You shouldn't edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Does it work if you update grub using `update-grub`?

Comment: yeah, I know I shouldn't edit grub.cfg, but I am looking for an easy work-around. It does not work using simply os-prober and update-grub2

Comment: your disk has a GUID partition table (gpt), so you need to post the ouput of `gdisk -l /dev/sda` rather than `fdisk`

Comment: as I said, I changed the partition table to MBR with gdisk. I have updated the output of fdisk and grub.cfg

Comment: it's probably the windows bootloader (and not grub) saying `Error: no such disk`.  Terdon's answer has it right - XP can't boot from a gpt disk.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, there is not any gpt disk anymore

Comment: try `(hd0, msdos3)` or try re-installing `os-prober` and running `update-grub` now that you've converted to MBR.

Comment: I have tried both, and they don't work. but when I mount the partition /dev/sda4 I can see that windows is there

Comment: just looking at that `fdisk` output hurts my brain. IMO your partition table is so messed up that you should backup your data, re-partition the disk and re-install everything from scratch.  install windows xp first into a primary partition.  then install linux and grub.

Comment: @cas I really don't see anything wrong with that partition table. Sure, it's not in order, and there is some wasted space, but I don't see anything overlapping (other than "extended" of course).

Comment: I'd suggest breaking into the grub command prompt (at the menu when booting the machine). Then I believe if you type "(hd, <TAB><TAB>" it'll give you a list of how it thinks you can complete that...

Comment: @derobert : the funny thing is that when I edit the linux entry and press <TAB> it does list the possible hard drive (hd0, hd0 msdos1, hd0 msdos4, hd0 msdos5, hd0 msdos6), but when I try to do the same with the winXP entry it doesn't list anything. Could it be that the menuentry I wrote is incomplete, and that I should add some additional parameters on the top?

Comment: All I see that's different is your entry has a space in it, the Linux one doesn't. You could also try adding that `insmod part_msdos` to your section.

Comment: I removed the space and put `insmod part_msdos`, now I don't get anymore an error message, but the systems simply restarts

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the [Microsoft docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463525.aspx) correctly (I should downvote you just for making me read that ;) ), XP cannot load from GPT disks:

> Q.    Can Windows XP x64 read, write, and boot from GPT disks?
>
> A.    Windows XP x64 Edition can use GPT disks for data only.
>
> Q.    Can the 32-bit version of Windows XP read, write, and boot from
>   GPT disks?
>
> A.   No. The 32-bit version will see only the Protective MBR. The EE partition will not be mounted or otherwise exposed to application
>   software.

So, it looks like even if you *could* get grub to see the windows installation, you still would not be able to boot into it from a GPT disk.

Comment: It could be possible with a carefully set up **hybrid** MBR.

Comment: does it mean I should reinstall Debian? but I do not remember any option that could be set during the installation process to change this behavious, I mean I do not remember that I had to choose gpt over mbr

Comment: @simona no, Debian is fine, it is XP that can't boot from a GPT disk. You have not explained how update-grub2 fails but my guess is that it found XP but simply cannot boot it because XP can't run from a GPT disk.

Comment: I think I made a mistake, both windows and debian are on the same disk, different partitions. because windows xp (32bit) is installed there, it can't be a gpt disk, can it? I thought it was a gpt disk because in the grub.cfg there is the entry root=(hd0,gpt1). I apologize for that

Comment: when I say that update-grub2 fails, I mean that after the update it doesn't add the windows partition to the boot menu

Comment: @simona please post your generated grub.cfg and the output of `df -h` and `sudo fdisk -l`.

Comment: I have added these information in my question

Comment: I am having some problem with this installation, sometimes it freezes and only the mouse works and nothing else, and I cannot quit applications and have to manually restart

Comment: I had previously successfully installed arch linux on this machine and in this attempt I chose a GPT partition table, following this instruction https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide#Choose_a_partition_table_type

Comment: Having installed arch linux, I recognized what the problem I was having in the installation of debian was and reverted to install debian, because I am more familiar with it. could it be the reason I find gpt in my debian installation? also if I don't remember I never selected this option over MBR in the debian installation

Comment: I have used the cd for installing arch linux and, with the tool gdisk, I have changed the partition table from gpt to msdos. I have reinstalled debian. Still I can't boot windows xp

Comment: @simona the `fdisk -l` shows you do have a gpt hard drive. Apparently booting XP from it is either very hard or impossible.

Comment: gpt vs mbr is only the kind of partition table, and I changed it with gdisk, in fact my updated version of fdisk does not show a gpt hard drive anymore

Comment: @simona then please update your question with the current situation, it is hard to follow from the comments. If it is mbr use `fdisk` if not post `gdisk` as Craig said.

Comment: I have updated all my question, fdisk does not show gpt anymore